# Angular: Bind an asynchronous service variable to template

Tags: angular

I am fetching the data from the backend and saving it in a variable in my service. I want to bind that to the respective component's template. I have tried using multiple methods but nothing is working for me.

Here's my code:

> service.ts

```
  getData()
{
  this.appService.postHTTPRequest(this.contactsURL).subscribe(response => {
    this.contactsData = response;
    console.log(this.contactsData);
}
, error => {
  console.log("An error has occurred");
});
}
```

> component.ts

```
ngOnInit()
{
  this.getData();
}

getData()
{
  this.contactsService.getData();  
}
```

> component.html

```
<tbody *ngFor = "let cData of contactsService.contactsData | async;" 
 style = "margin:auto;">
<tr>
  <td>{{cData.data[0].name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Its not working. Can anybody tell me how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Can you put code in stackblitz?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting errors? Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Answer (score 0):

Your `contactsData` in the service doesn't seems to be an `Observable` then why are you using an `async` pipe. Remove it. Additionally you can check if it not null or undefined using `ngIf`

```
<table *ngIf = "contactsService.contactsData && contactsService.contactsData.length > 0">
<tbody *ngFor = "let cData of contactsService.contactsData">
 <tr>
 <td>{{cData.data[0].name}}</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If you want to make use of any `Observable` update your service file

```
getData() {
  this.contactsData$ = this.appService.postHTTPRequest(this.contactsURL);
}
```

and template:

```
<table *ngIf = "(contactsService.contactsData$ | async) as contacts">
<tbody *ngFor = "let cData of contacts">
 <tr>
 <td>{{cData.data[0].name}}</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

PS: Added **$ suffix** to indicate that variable is an `Observable`.

Comment: `contactsService.contactsData && contactsService.contactsData.length > 0` is superfluous in an Angular template. You can achieve the same logic with a simple `contactsService.contactsData?.length`. Also, its worth mentioning that your proposed `contactsData$` binding method  is likely to cause the template to make several HTTP requests for the same data - definitely a pattern worth avoiding, especially when you can achieve the desired outcome with an rxjs `Subject` or `BehaviourSubject` and better manage your HTTP requests.

Comment: Agree with length check part, I just kept it simpler to understand.. but I don't see any issue with `Observable` part, I have used it many places myself, you can always make use of `shareReplay()` to avoid multiple http calls.. you can try it yourself